# シミュレータで現在位置やFreeway Driveの選択項目がでないときがある

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

[iOS Simulator での現在位置の設定をすると捗る](https://qiita.com/mattak/items/420039c674fe4392a647) にあるとおり、
シミュレータの現在位置をAppleにしたり、Freeway Driveにしたりといった選択ができるはずなのですが、
添付画像に示す通り、選択項目がありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

はじめ選択できなくて、色々やってるうちに選べるようになったので、数日触っていたのですが、別件でGitブランチを切り替えて他の作業をしたせいか、はたまたチームメンバーによって開発が進んだせいか、もう一度、該当作業中のブランチに戻ったら、選択てきなくなってしまっていました（おそらく上記にあげた原因は関係ないと思いますが...）

一体、どうすれば選べるようになるのでしょうか？（またそのうち色々やってるうちに選択できそうになりそうですが、確実に選べるように方法が知りたいです）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109634

> Restarting my macbook resolved the issue.

とあるように、XcodeをQuitしてMacをシャットダウンして、起動させると選べるようになりました...（今日はすでに数回再起動させたはずなのだが...）

（あと、XcodeのIndexingが終わるまで実行しない等もしてみました... また色々やってしまった...）